# make action method only accessible through redirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to submit a form. When the form is submitted I want the form to dissapear and the text `Thanks for your support. An e-mail will be sent to you as soon as possible.` to show.

I think the most logical way to go by this is by making the form submit to the action `SaveMessage()` that redirects to  the action `RedirectToAction("MessageSaved")` that returns the view with the message. If it isn't, please say so. This is for practice.

The problem is that the message can be viewed as well by going to `/Support/MessageSaved`. How do I prevent users from accessing it by url, but make the action accessible by `redirectToAction()`?

Comment: "the message can be viewed as well by going to `/Support/MessageSaved`" - why is this a problem?

Comment: @GalacticCowboy It's not that something awful would happen, but it seems weird to me if I would allow it to be viewed by users that aren't supposed to view it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a value in `TempData` before the redirect.  In the `MessageSaved` action method, check for that value before showing the form.  Otherwise, redirect to another page.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense :P I was kind of expecting some kind of built-in action filter that would prevent this.

Comment: would you just keep the action open for everyone to view?

Comment: @user1534664 Since it's just an information message, it doesn't seem to harm anything.  If somebody was poking around your app to this degree, it's more important to make sure they can't see any "protected" information.